# Disappearing shared folder?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-server

I had the sharing that had been setup on a folder mysteriously disappear over the weekend (the folder itself was left alone) and I am at a loss to figure out what could have caused this to happen.  I spoke with the server guy and apparently there was a windows update that ran followed by a blue screen at which point he rebooted.  It seems like a long shot but I'm wondering if this could have had something to do with it?

Has anyone heard of something like this happening before?  Suggestions on where to look to find the cause so I can try and prevent it in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst not ideal, it can happen.

Through my company, I manage a few large networks and this sort of thing happens all the time - the most common cause is network resetting, service packs or corrupt profiles.

Depending on how you use and manage your computers, there isn't anything you can easily do about it in most scenarios.

If however you are using Active Directory, rather than relying on people ticking the "reconnect at logon" option, you can always use a logon script or other techniques to assign the map drive at logon.